# WPF bind ComboBox with CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, combobox

I would like to bind a ComboBox with a CheckBox so that the ComboBox is enabled when the CheckBox is **not checked**.
Can I do that directly in the xaml file, without adding any additional variable in the code?
In the code below, myComboBox is enabled when myCheckBox **is ckecked**.

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox" SelectedIndex="0" 
     IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a converter to convert the Boolean values to it's inverted value. In order to do that first create a class the inherits from IValueConverter like this:

```
public sealed class InvertedBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert( Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if ( value is Boolean )
        {
            return (Boolean)value ? false : true;
        }

        return null;
    }


    public Object ConvertBack( Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you need to add the converter in the resources like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:InvertedBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And lastly just add the converter to the binding like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="myComboBox"
          SelectedIndex="0"
          IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConverter}}">
```